# Cannot convert String Object to String in php

Tags: php, string, ionic-framework, jwt, laravel-5.3

I've been stuck on this one for a while now. I am working with json web tokens in laravel, and am using the [jwt-auth framework](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), and I'm using it in conjunction with the ionic 2 framework to validate logins. The problem lies with the parseToken method. Following the code, I found that from [parseToken() to setToken()](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/JWTAuth.php), the string converts to a string object, and I'm unsure of why. Fixing that would be another solution, but the solution I was going for is to convert the string object into a regular string, so I can use the explode function, which is required in [tokenValidator](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Validators/TokenValidator.php).

I have read that you cannot convert from objects to strings, but when I converted from string object to string, it worked in the context of an echo. It was able to echo out the string, it's length, and properly use the explode function, but laravel still tells me that I cannot convert from type object to string. Any thoughts guys?

```
public function parseToken($method = 'bearer', $header = 'authorization', $query = 'token')
{
    if (! $token = $this->parseAuthHeader($header, $method)) {
        if (! $token = $this->request->query($query, false)) {
            throw new JWTException('The token could not be parsed from the request', 400);
        }
    }
    return $this->setToken($token);
}
```

And then from tokenValidator

```
if (count(explode('.', $token)) !== 3) {
        throw new TokenInvalidException('Wrong number of segments');
    }

    return true;
```

Here's the error(The echo of string is from an earlier gettype call):

[image: Pic of error]

Comment: `explode('.', (string)$token)` will fix your issue.

Comment: Maybe you aren't calling the exception class properly. From one of the examples `$this->manager->shouldReceive('decode')->once()->andThrow(new TokenInvalidException);` there isn't any variables in exception class contructor

Comment: Why would you convert object to string like this, can't you take the string from the token object? try to do `explode('.', $token->getToken())`